# Intelligent Tiering Issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I was hoping to get other's perspective on something that we've done and beginning to realize it was not the *best* idea.

Here's some information about our "environment":

- Account A: We have an AWS account that acts as a data lake (we upload transaction data to S3 daily)
- Account B: We have another AWS account that our business partners use to access the data in Account A

A few months back, we enabled Intelligent Tiering in S3 where objects are moved to Archive and Deep Archive in 90 and 180 days, respectively. We're now seeing the downfall of this decision. OUr business partners are unable to query data (in account A) from 3 months ago in Athena (account B). Oof.

I guess we did not understand the purpose of intelligent tiering and had hoped that Athena would be able to move tiered objects back into standard s3 when someone queries the data (as in instant retrieval).

There's definitely some use cases that we missed in vetting intelligent tiering.

I am curious how are others leveraging intelligent tiering? Are you only tiering objects that your business partners do not need as "instant retrieval"?

Comment: If you are looking for 'opinions', you might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws

Answer (score 1):

If you goal is to reduce Storage costs, it is worth investigating and understanding the various Storage Classes offered by Amazon S3.

They generally fall into three categories:

- **Instantly available:** This is the 'standard' class
- **Instantly available, lower storage cost but higher retrieval cost:** This is the 'Infrequent Access' classes. They can be cheaper for data that is only accessed **once per month or less**. If they are accessed more often, then the Request charges outweigh the savings in Storage costs.
- **Archived:** This is typically the Glacier classes. Avoid them if you want to use Amazon Athena.

See that table on: [Comparing the Amazon S3 storage classes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-class-intro.html#sc-compare)

For your use-case, you might consider keeping data in **Standard** by default (since it is heavily accessed), and then move data older than 90 days to **S3 One Zone - Infrequent Access**. It will still be accessible, but will have a lower storage cost if rarely used.

I would also recommend converting your data to **Snappy-compressed Parquet format** (preferably partitioned), which will reduce the amount of storage required and will allow Athena to selectively pick which objects it needs to access. It will will also make Athena run faster and reduce the cost of Athena queries.

See: [Top 10 Performance Tuning Tips for Amazon Athena | AWS Big Data Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/)

Comment: Hi, John. I find it difficult to pinpoint how often data past 90 days get accessed. The reason for this is because this is an analytics space. Our business partners want free reign of the data. Some use data as far back as 10 years (actuarial). Others us at least 5 years of data for predicting models.

Typing this out makes me really wonder how we missed this use case. :)

Comment: For the "S3 One Zone-IA" storage class, I'm trying to understand the implication that it's "not resilient to the loss of the Availability Zone". We're currently replicating our data into another region (us-west-2). So, it seems we'd have this cover.

Although, does data in this storage class get retrieved when querying in athena or does an actual restore need to occur?

Comment: **Infrequent Access** classes are instantly available, but there is an additional `$0.01 per GB` charge for "data retrieval" (this would apply when the data is access via Amazon Athena). This is balanced against the lower storage cost of `$0.01 per GB` vs `$0.023 per GB` for Standard. Since storage is about 1c/GB cheaper, but access costs 1c/GB, Infrequent Access is only worthwhile if the data is accessed less than once per month. If you are using compressed columnar storage (eg Snappy-compressed Parquet format files), then the amount of data accessed will be lessened.

Comment: All Amazon S3 data is replicated within a Data Center (that is, within an AZ), but it is _also_ replicated between AZs. If you choose the **One Zone** storage class and an AZ fails, then your data might be inaccessible/lost. (It is extremely rare that this could happen, but it could happen.) If you have another copy of the data somewhere (eg on your own systems), then you could recover the data from there.

Comment: If you are replicating your data to another region, then you're effectively paying twice for storage and I would question why you are doing this. If it is for "backup", then S3 offers sufficient backup under Standard storage (replicated _within_ an AZ and replicated _amongst_ AZs). The chance of a total Region outage is low, but some companies choose to replicate infrastructure/data between regions.